# Union tables of dataset in a single datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DataSet with many similar tables in it. I need to union all datatables in a single table. So for this example; I need a datatable with 20 rows. How can I do that?

```
DataSet SampleDS = new DataSet();

DataTable SampleTbl1 = new DataTable();
SampleTbl1.Columns.Add("Product", typeof(string));
SampleTbl1.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    SampleTbl1.Rows.Add("Product " + i, i);
}

SampleDS.Tables.Add(SampleTbl1);

DataTable SampleTbl2 = new DataTable();
SampleTbl2.Columns.Add("Product", typeof(string));
SampleTbl2.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    SampleTbl2.Rows.Add("Product " + i, i*2);
}

SampleDS.Tables.Add(SampleTbl2);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a new DataTable, then import rows of two tables into new table.

```
DataTable t = new DataTable();
t.Columns.Add("Product", typeof(string));
t.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));

foreach(DataTable table in SampleDS.Tables)
{
if(table != null && table.Rows.Count > 0)
{
for(int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i ++)
t.ImportRow(table.Rows[i]);
}
}
```

HTH.

Answer (score 2):

Try with LINQ

```
var table = SampleDS.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();

for (var ii = 1; ii < SampleDS.Tables.Count; ii++) {
  table = table.Concat(SampleDS.Tables[ii].AsEnumerable());
}
```